# jQuery function not working on iOS mobile devices

Tags: jquery, ios, mobile

On my website, I am using a jQuery function to display different sections of content without reloading the page. It works fine on computers, but not on iOS devices (I have not tried Android). Have any idea what I need to do?

The problem is on clicking the post it notes at [hiredustinhill.com](http://hiredustinhill.com)

JQuery function for menu nav and post it notes:

```
jQuery('#header ul li a').click(function(){
        var thisClass = jQuery(this).attr("rel");
        jQuery("div.slide").stop(true, true).css('display', 'none');
        jQuery("."+thisClass).animate({opacity: "show", height: "show"}, "slow");
        jQuery('#header ul li.active').removeClass("active");
        jQuery(this).parent("li").addClass("active");
        return false;
    });
    jQuery('#postit-click a').click(function(){
        var thisClass = jQuery(this).attr("rel");
        jQuery('header ul li.active').html('Variable: '+thisClass);
        jQuery("div.slide").stop(true, true).css('display', 'none');
        jQuery("."+thisClass).animate({opacity: "show", height: "show"}, "slow");
        jQuery('#header ul li.active').removeClass("active");
        jQuery(thisClass).addClass("active");
        return false;
    });
```

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Patience is the key! Ha ha :) I'm not really sure why it wasn't working on my iPad or iPhone, but it is working now. I looked into the jQuery documentation and saw that there shouldn't be any troubles. Glad it works!